# Subtree definition confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, definition

Let $A$ be a finite prefix-closed set with operation $\cdot$ (so $A$ is a semigroup, "prefix-closed" means that if $x\cdot y\in A$, then $x\in A$ as well, it is not necessarily about strings, btw).

Consider the following set, which we call *the subtree* with root at the node $a$:

$B|_a=\{b\mid a\cdot b\in A\}$.

My question is: does this definition imply that:

$\forall a'=a\cdot b\in A\Rightarrow b\in B|_a$?

**UPD**, in other words, let us consider the following example:

let $A=\{1, 1\cdot 1,1\cdot 2,1\cdot 3\}$, consider $B|_1$. Will it be necessarily $\{1,2,3\}$, or it can be $\{1,2\}$ or $\{2,3\}$?

**UPD-2**: I expected that the answer is **yes**. But in this case, how I should properly describe/define the case when $B|_1$ can be $\{1,2\}$ as well?

Comment: What does "prefix-closed" mean? Usually I know that term used about sets of strings/words over some alphabet, but in your question $A$ is just some set with a binary operation.

Comment: Prefix closed means that if $x\cdot y\in A$, then $x\in A$. It is not my invention, this kind of terminology is often used in papers about tree languages.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Excuse me,  did I explain it well or I have to clarify it more?

Comment: Yes, the definition implies that.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I am very appreciated for your answer/comment (that actually is what I did expect). But could you please be so kind and answer  me: how I should describe the $B|_a$ set, if I want to allow it be only a partial subtree, like $\{1,2\}$ in my example?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Also I will be glad to upvote and accept your answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Andremoniy: I'm still confused -- you have introduced $\cdot$ as a binary operation on $A$, so $x\cdot y$ is not even meaningful unless $x\in A$. Is your $\cdot$ secretly an operation defined on a _larger_ set than $A$ which you have not said anything about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, this is partially a notation question about set
builder notation. If there is no specified set which the
expression of the notation is iterating over (such as
the positive integers in $\{x \in \mathbb Z_{>0}: x < 10\}$)
the notation is frankly ambiguous.

So supposing there is some universal set $S$, this is how I read your definition of $B|_a$.

*For a fixed $a$,
for all $b$ in $S$,
$b \in B|_a$ if
and only if  $a \cdot b \in A$.*

So if $A=\{1, 1\cdot 1,1\cdot 2,1\cdot 3\}$, and $S = \{1,2,3\}$,
then $B|_1$ will be precisely $\{1,2,3\}$.

The other part of your question, if you wish to describe a set $B'$ such that

*For a fixed $a$, if $b \in B'$ then
$a \cdot b \in A$.*

You are then not defining a single set but a collection of sets.
The property that defines them is $B' \subseteq B|_a$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $B|_a$ is the set $\{b \mid a \cdot b \in A\}$. This is just set-builder notation which means that if $a \cdot b \in A$, then we have $b \in B|_a$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Hence, if $A = \{1, 1 \cdot 1, 1 \cdot 2, 1 \cdot 3\}$, then $B|_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$.